# Turn-By-Turn to integrate on my android app

Tags: android, navigation

I'm developing a system that needs turn-by-turn (TomTom like), and it should be embedded in my app.
So I can have a side menu to switch form navigation to other stuff.
Can I embed Tomtom or other on my app, or should I use other with an android SDK to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Tom Tom is one of the top turn by turn auto navigation app. I dont believe the let you it to your app and also they have not publish any library for embedding purpose.

But there are many other useful API developed for same purpose.
Some of them are:

1. [MapQuest](http://developer.mapquest.com/)
2. [DeCarta](http://www.decarta.com/products/tbt_navigation.html)
3. [osmbonuspack](http://developer.mapquest.com/)

There are others too, and also heard android has its own turn by turn API. But I would suggest you to use MapQuest cause much more well documented and has always been developers choice.

Comment: I have heard a lot of map quest I'll take a look. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't embed or integrate another app into yours.

However, you can launch a third party app that supports the functionality you need.

For example, in case of turn by turn navigation, I'm supporting Google Navigation and Waze.
Both will provide turn by turn navigation to the coordinates that you send on the Intent data.

For Google Navigation

```
google.navigation:q=[LAT],[LON]
```

For Waze

```
waze://?ll=[LAT],[LON]&navigate=yes
```

For launching them

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(intent);
```

I would recomend checking for this apps being installed before launching them. You can do this by querying the package manager with the package name's, or checking for components able to handle the given intent.

Comment: I need to have a fast way to get back to my app. So I will have a side menu that have several fast options. If I launch outside my app I won't have so fast return. I also want to be able to fast swap from navigation to my app options. I also need some fixed indicators to be present all the time. Thanks.